# Domino Designer not syncing properly

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

In a rather complex project the entire project team is encountering more and more problems regarding designer, like frequent crashes, exceeding of memory limits and- most annoying - problems with outdated project data:

quite often we observe that two different designer clients are showing different versions of project data (see below for a rough description of the environment).

A simple example: an hour ago a co-worker asked me to open and test a new Xpage she had created 15 minutes ago in her Designer. In my Designer client however the new Xpage was not present yet. right-clicking my application and hitting "refresh" brought up the new Xpage.

The problem hits the ceiling with design elements that we both are working on in turns (as in "are you currently working on xpage XXX? I'd like to add..."). So with this syncing delay the problem is obvious: If I foirget to manually sync my project before adding stuff I will overwrite the co-workers' codings.

We never had this problem before, although I have to admit that we never had to work in a team on such a massive project.

Here's the setup:

- all designer clients are 9.0.1 FP6
- everyone is working on the same project stored on the same server
- everyone is working on the same network withion the same building, just door-to-door

Is there something we could do or check to improve this situation?

Comment: We experienced this as well. The only thing to at least prohibit that two of you work on the same elements is "Design- Element- Locking". If enabled it might help. 

It is not the best solution for our problem, but at least part of the solution.

Comment: we tried this as well but ran into other problems so we disabled the feature. But it didn't help anyways for the situation described here: we are in fact performing a stone-age version of design locking as in "...could you please get out of..., because I need to...". So the problem is NOT that we're working on the same thing at the same time, but even after the co-worker has left the element, I still find the old version in my designer, and this is not a matter of a few seconds but of 15 or even 30 minutes

Comment: Use source control!

Comment: In fact we're considering to do so for other reasons. But what benefits would that bring in the context described here?

Comment: It would solve your sync problems, your "waiting for each other" problems and your high risk of losing code changes :-)

Comment: You may need to disable "Use Binary DXL for source control operations" to be able to perform merges outside of Designer. Many XPages developers will recommend SourceTree as a Git/Mercurial client. For merges I use Perforce P4Merge, again free. It is a different way of working, but one that is standard when moving beyond Domino. Search for "show and tell source control xpages" for resources, including my Show and Tell and NotesIn9.

Comment: I hate to say it, but adding source control into the mix will likely make things worse unless you plan things carefully (ref. the whole virtual-file-system-are-my-changes-there-or-not mess in Designer). See the IBM wiki for more tips: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewTags.xsp?categoryFilter=source%20control

Comment: many thanks everyone, in regards to source control; in fact before starting the project I had planned to start with source control right from the beginning; unfortunately our sys admins didn't manage to get a gitlab server up and running in time (not their fault, I have to say). Now that we're in the middle of the project facing a very tight schedule I don't feel like starting an experiment here. Next time. - Still the question is: what syncing frequency between server and client can I expect (if at all)?

Comment: Watch my words: start source control NOW. You don't need a gitlab server, a simple git install will do (on a machine both can reach). While you are on it: use headless mode to build the database. So you two don't work on the same NSF, you work on your local version. Saves you lots of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Lothar, you have stated three problems at once. I'll try dissect them.

**Frequent crashes:** 
We experienced many, many crashes in our daily work after upgrading to Windows 10. I know it sounds silly, but one way it worked for us and successfully mitigated those crashes was installing IBM Designer into C:\IBM\Notes, instead of C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes. 
Granting 'Full Access' to 'All Users' over that folder was also necessary.

**Exceeding of memory limits:** As *jtomas* correctly pointed out, default memory settings are not enough for heavy xpages development in Domino Designer. I would suggest going to `vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx1024m`.

**Problems with outdated project data:** I think there is no workaround for this problem because there is no problem. Domino Designer 9 is a Eclipse based software, and works like so.

Think about it: When working in Java projects, developers download (checkout) source files from a Source Control System (SVN, Git, etc) and work them locally. Whenever a developer modifies or create a file, another developer can see it only if:

a) The modified/new file has been uploaded (commit) to Source Control Repository; and

b) Other developers have synchronized (refresh) their local projects with the repository.

See, that's how Java development works and that's the way we should do it too. Upon opening a NSF file, Domino Designer breaks it down into many files, just like a Java project. Once locally saved into the Java Virtual File System, those files get updates only when you refresh the project. Silly, but it is what it is.

My recipe to a well succeeded Domino development team include:

**1) Design locking:** All developers must explicitly lock elements they will work on. We don't rely on implicit locks.

**2) Communications:** All members of the team must be immediately notified whenever a developer has made major updates to the project.

**3) Source Control:** Despite its pitfalls, we rely heavily on SVN as code repository. It's far from perfect, and merges don't work properly, but it's better than no control.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will fix your syncing issue but I have found modifying the following 3 lines in your local Notes\framework\rcp\deploy\jvm.properties file to help with Designer performance when developing in XPages especially with large projects:

```
vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx512m
vmarg.Xms=-Xms48m
vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca512k
```

These are the memory limits I use. You can increase the limits just make sure they are a multiple of 4. You have to restart Notes & Designer for changes to take effect.

Comment: thanx; we already set those to 1024m / 1024m / 512k. totally agree that this seems to improve overall performance of designer; unfortunately it didn't help improve stability :(

Comment: What also helps: have Designer installed like a Notes client in "shared" mode. The data directory belongs into the user profile, not elsewhere